# simple Query phpipam in powershell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, powershell, rest, api

I have a code in python and I would like to do the same in powershell. 
This code works to make inquiries in the phpipam api.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

server = "http://phpipam.local"
appid = "nuevoid"
username = "admin"
password = "password"

baseurl = server + "/api/" + appid

res = requests.post(baseurl + '/user/', auth=(username, password))
token = json.loads(res.content)['data']['token']

res = requests.get(baseurl + '/addresses/search/192.168.10.10', headers={'token': token})
dip = json.loads(res.content)['data']
df = pd.DataFrame(dip)
print(df[['ip','hostname','custom_dns_name','editDate','is_gateway','owner']])
```

`Invoke-WebRequest`

```
$url = "http://phpipam.local/api/nuevoid/addresses/search/192.168.10.10"
$bearer_token = "asdasdasdZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
$headers = @{token = "$bearer_token"}


#$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing


$headers=@{ Authorization = "Bearer $bearer_token";"Content-Type"="text/xml" }

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $url -Method GET
```

I don't know how I could do the same type of authorization in powershell. In Python Works OK!

The error in the query is: {"code":401,"success":false,"message":"Unauthorized","time":0.002} –

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: The error in the query is: {"code":401,"success":false,"message":"Unauthorized","time":0.002}